# How to check if policy ID contains four number exact match in Django

Tags: python, django

Asking for help on how to detect existing policy that has exact match on filename.
Example : GIRL**4876**S is still passed even though BOY**4876**T already exists.

```
def policy_exists(policy_id, ref=None):
filename = policy_id + '.xml'
try:
    if ref:
        repo.get_contents('policies/' + filename, ref)
    else:
        # no ref default = previous release commit
        repo.get_contents('policies/' + filename, prev_release_commit())
    return True
except UnknownObjectException:
    return False

def submit_new(submissions):
errors = []
for sub in submissions:
    if sub.attrib['defect_type'] != 'NV':
        errors.append('Invalid defect type: ' + sub.attrib['defect_type'])
    if gh.policy_exists(sub.attrib['policy_id']):
        errors.append('Existing Policy: ' + sub.attrib['policy_id'])
    # if sub.attrib['policy_id'].endswith('T'):
    #     errors.append('Terminate policy ' + sub.attrib['policy_id'] + ' is not allowed for this submission type')

branch_name = 'NEW-' + ','.join(str(s.attrib['policy_id']) for s in submissions)

return branch_name, errors
```

since both GIRL**4876**S and BOY**4876**T has 4876 on them. The function should append error.

Comment: Is it a CharField?

Comment: please provide model